# Equation environment already defined

Tags: equations

I am using `iopart.cls` and `iopams.sty` and no other mathematical package as by the guidelines here: https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/

However, I am getting an annoying "Command \equation* already defined."

Can anyone help me in finding what's wrong, or more precisely what's wrong in the preamble that follows?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP Publishing journals}}
%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required
\usepackage{iopams}  
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\bbE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\bbP}{\mathbb{P}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `yhmath` package has `\RequirePackage{amsmath}`, so you can't load it, unless you *do* load `amsmath` as described below.

For mysterious reasons `iopart` prevents loading `amsmath` by providing a  definition of `equation*` that could be moved `\AtBeginDocument` in case `amsmath` is not loaded.

Instead of forcing you to use the broken `eqnarray`, you can easily load `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}

% allow loading amsmath
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax
%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required
\usepackage{iopams}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\bbE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\bbP}{\mathbb{P}}

\newcommand{\gguide}{{\itshape Preparing graphics for IOP Publishing journals}}
```

---

Lines 788-789 of `iopart.cls`, instead of

```
\@namedef{equation*}{\[}
\@namedef{endequation*}{\]}
```

should be

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{}{%
    \@namedef{equation*}{\[}%
    \@namedef{endequation*}{\]}%
  }%
}
```

This is the ***only*** incompatibility between `iopart` and `amsmath`. I'm not sure why the developers planted it in.

Answer (score 2):

On page 2 of your class documentation:

> Also note that there is an incompatibility between `amsmath.sty` and `iopart.cls` which cannot be completely worked around. If your article relies on commands in `amsmath.sty` that are not available in `iopart.cls`, you may wish to consider using a different class file.

So any package that loads `amsmath` will make the document uncompilable.

That's a bit surprising, honestly. How long has `amsmath` been a standard package for LaTeX, again?

Comment: The developers of the class ***planted in*** the incompatibility, for no apparent reason.